# Error in docker compose with service application

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

ERROR: The Compose file '.\docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:                                                                                                                                                                           Unsupported config option for services.db: 'pessoa'

My docker-compose

```
version: '3.7'
services:
    db:
      image: felipe/postgresql-pessoa
      build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
      environment:
        TZ: Americana/Sao_Paulo
        POSTGRES_USER: postgres
        POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 123
        POSTGRES_DBNAME: postgres
      ports:
       - "5435:5435"
      networks:
        - pessoa-network  
      pessoa:
        image: felipe/pessoa-udemy
        restart: always
        build: ./Pessoa
        work_dir: /Pessoa
        environment:
        TZ: Americana/Sao_Paulo
        SPING_BOOT_ENVIRONMENT: Production
        volumes:
            - ./Pessoa: /Pessoa
            - ~/ .m2:/root/ .m2 
      ports: 
        - "8082:8082"
      command: mvn clean spring-boot:run
      links:
         - db
      depends_on:
         - db
      networks:
         - pessoa-network          
networks:
    pessoa-network:
        driver: bridge
```

Comment: From `pessoa:` down to the end of its `volumes:` block is indented one step too many.

Comment: im try this but get a new error

Comment: ERROR: In file '.\docker-compose.yml', service 'ports' must be a mapping not an array.

Answer (score 1):

Better to test [docker-compose online validator](https://codebeautify.org/yaml-validator/cbccd63a) as there is indentation issue in the compose file.

Also, there is no config option `work_dir` it should be `working_dir`

Here is the fix docker-compose file.

```
version: '3.7'
services:
    db:
      image: felipe/postgresql-pessoa
      build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
      environment:
        TZ: Americana/Sao_Paulo
        POSTGRES_USER: postgres
        POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 123
        POSTGRES_DBNAME: postgres
      ports:
        - "5435:5435"
      networks:
        - pessoa-network  
    pessoa:
      image: felipe/pessoa-udemy
      restart: always
      build: ./Pessoa
      working_dir: /Pessoa
      environment:
        TZ: Americana/Sao_Paulo
        SPING_BOOT_ENVIRONMENT: Production
      volumes:
        - "./Pessoa:/Pessoa"
      ports: 
        - "8082:8082"
      command: mvn clean spring-boot:run
      links:
         - db
      depends_on:
         - db
      networks:
         - pessoa-network          
networks:
    pessoa-network:
        driver: bridge
```